# Flutter Hero with Text widget that changes style

Tags: flutter, animation, text

I'm trying to transition a Text Widget between two screens (using Hero widget).
I'd like the Text Widget to change its style between these two screens (let's say FontSize).

Implementing it resulting in a strange behavior: the text doesn't change its size smoothly but rather has jerky animation...

Any idea on how to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

recently, I published a Package HERO_TEXT
https://pub.dev/packages/hero_text
it seems to me that it can help you.